# how to load modules into other modules in knockout js AMD helpers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-amd-helpers

how can i load javascript modules into another module for use for example i want to have one moudule having an object which i want to use to create instances of that object in another module.

example: object module:

`

```js
define(["knockout"],function(){
   var postobj = function(name,age){
     this.name = ko.observable(name);
     this.age = ko.observable(age);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

and for the second part of the module i have this code

```js
define(["knockout"],function(ko){
  this.posts = ko.observableArray();
  
  var people = [{name: "katuula Kalali Joel", age: "23"},
                {name: "keman Migadde", age: "30"},
                {name: "Ntanda Hakim", age: "19"}];
  
  jQuery.each(people,function(index,value){
                    this.posts.push(new imageobj(value['name'],value['age']));
                },this);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

i get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: postobj is not defined "

Answer (score 2):

You would want to pull your original module in as a reference to the second module. In the second one, it looks like you are using `imageobj`, but I am assuming that it would be a similar scenario to your `postobj`.

So, you would want your modules to look something like:

```
define(["knockout"],function(){
   var postobj = function(name,age){
     this.name = ko.observable(name);
     this.age = ko.observable(age);
   };

    // important to return the value of your module
    return postobj;
});
```

In the second module, you would pull in your first module like:

```
define(["knockout", "path/to/postobj"],function(ko, Postobj){
  function ViewModel() {
      this.posts = ko.observableArray();

      var people = [{name: "katuula Kalali Joel", age: "23"},
                {name: "keman Migadde", age: "30"},
                {name: "Ntanda Hakim", age: "19"}];

      jQuery.each(people,function(index,value){
                    this.posts.push(new Postobj(value['name'],value['age']));
                },this);

  }

  return new ViewModel();

});
```

Comment: thanx very much ryan, your a life saver after 48hrs of hustle